# What log files does a WordPress installation write to?

Tags: errors

When tracking down WordPress problems, I've had a hard time finding where WordPress sends errors to. Where does WordPress send errors by default? Are there multiple files that different kinds of errors are directed to?

(I'm either a terribly ungifted Googler or WordPress's own documentation is hard to sort through.)

Comment: Check /var/log/apache2/error.log , that's often the default location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where (or if) errors are logged is dependent on your php configuration. You can control some of this via your WordPress `wp-config.php file`. See [Configure Error Logging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Logging) in [Editing wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php).

Comment: Excellent, I was wondering how to control WordPress's output of errors, but thought I should save that specific question for a new topic. I'll look into that as I try and track down some recent problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to it on that system (unlikely on a shared host) have a look in the messages log. I've found most failures will log something in there. You might also check the web server logs. As far as I'm aware Wordpress doesn't generate it's own logs.

Comment: It's on a VPS that I own and operate so I've got total control of it. I've poked through `/var/log/messages` as a first line of troubleshooting and it seems that major systems that WordPress relies on will of course write information there, but WordPress's own internal error handling doesn't seem to put anything useful there. So if there's the infamous "white screen of death" nothing of use shows up. That's more of a PHP error though, and I haven't seen WordPress write PHP errors anywhere consistently. =/

Comment: @WesleyDavid, In such a case I do turn on full logging for PHP but of course that has it's own problems if the system is already open to the public.

Comment: I think I shall do that and make some kind of deployment script that turns on logging and points errors to a protected file or set of files. I'm frustrated that the default for WordPress is to not have at least some level of PHP error logging take place. Maybe I'm just permanently set to Cranky-Mode though.

Comment: @WesleyDavid, you need to bear in mind that the very vast majority of Wordpress users are not admins and would be overwhelmed and possibly driven away by the sort of information you and I want to see. Welcome to the user end of things. ;)